# Set internal clock from code in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, clock

I have a requirement where I need to set the internal clock of iPad from inside my code. I did some google on it with no fruitful result. Is it at all possible to do it and if yes, how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't using official APIs, it's up to the user to change the time on the device. Moreover, the user can't even control when it's set/updated if it's using Apple's time servers.

You can however maintain your own time inside your app using for example this:
https://code.google.com/p/ios-ntp/

If you really need to change the clock, you might have a look on Cydia, [this](http://modmyi.com/cydia/com.hanjo-net.ntpdate) app for instance can change the device's internal clock connecting to custom NTP servers.

Also, some time ago I read this [article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/what_time_is_it_your_ipad_ios_5_finally_knows) about how time synchronisation works on iOS that you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible unless you jailbreak.  That is a setting for the user, not for your app.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, No its not possible. Setting system settings is out of the purview of the iPhone developers' SDK. The API's to access such functions are not documented for users to set.